# Very slow VS2017 C++ linker speed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, linker, visual-studio-2017

We're upgrading our C++ projects from VS2013 to VS2017. But in VS2017 we have very bad linking times also for Debug builds. With such values, it's not possible to do effective development.

When I change the single file in our project, in VS2013 it takes 2.6sec. When I do the same with the same file in VS2017 it takes 30sec.

```
VS2013
1>       32 ms  ComputeCLOutputs                           1 calls
1>      199 ms  WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename              1 calls
1>     2688 ms  Link                                       1 calls
1>     4073 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls

VS2017
1>       31 ms  ComputeCLOutputs                           1 calls
1>       44 ms  CustomBuild                                1 calls
1>      239 ms  WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename              1 calls
1>     8021 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls
1>    29725 ms  Link                                       1 calls
```

This is more than 15x slower than in VS2013.

Currently, I have both Visual Studios installed on my PC so I can test it side-by-side. I tried a lot of things as same as a lot of googling but without success.

I tried:

- compile the same project in VS2017 but with VS2013 toolset and linking takes 2.6sec. So the problem is with toolset in VS2017 not with VS2017 IDE.
- I tried a lot of combinations with DebugInformationFormat like /Zi and /Z7, as same as /DEBUG vs /DEBUG:Fastlink, /INCREMENTAL,... but any other settings is even worse than default one generated by QMake (/Zi + /DEBUG:Fastlink + /INCREMENTAL).
- I also tried 32bit and 64bit compiler/linker as same as 32/64bit target. But it doesn't have any impact on performance.
- I tried to convert VS2013 project to VS2017 as same as generating new one via Qt Qmake but also without any differences.

During link time CPU isn't used at 100% as same as SSD drive isn't utilized at 100%. I tried to output verbose linking log but there isn't anything special (no foreign temporary files, etc. like mentioned in other answers).

This is complete compiler command line

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /MP /GS /analyze- /W3 /wd"4577" /wd"4467" /Zc:wchar_t /I ...INCLUDE FOLDERS... /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"objs\Debug32\" /FI"stdafx.h" /fp:precise 
/D "_WINDOWS" /D "UNICODE" /D "WIN32" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"objs\Debug32\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"objs\Debug32\" 
/Fp"Debug32\\App.pch" /diagnostics:classic 

-Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zm130 -w44996 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458
```

And linker command line

```
/OUT:"Debug32\\App.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"Debug32\App.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "Q:\SharedLibraries2017\Qt32\lib\qtmaind.lib" "shell32.lib" ...
 /VERSION:"1.0" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"Debug32\App.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
 /ManifestFile:"_App\objs\Debug32\App.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"Q:\SharedLibraries2017\Qt32\lib" /TLBID:1 

"/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"
```

I found few some posts about slow linking but nothing helped for me (64bit, erasing temporary files, turning of synchro/sourcurce control/codelens/diagnostic, clean build in new folders, ... ).

I'm using latest VS2017 version 15.5.6, toolset v141, SDK 10.0.16299.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Added:

My PC setup is:
i7-7700K CPU @ 4.2Ghz
16GB Ram
SSD Drive 
Latest Win10

Edited:

I tried another (smaller) project.

When I do complete rebuild, I got these results:

```
VS2013:
1>     2898 ms  Link                                       1 calls
1>    11987 ms  CustomBuild                                1 calls
1>    68238 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls

VS2017
1>     2822 ms  Link                                       1 calls
1>    14221 ms  CustomBuild                                1 calls
1>    67243 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls
```

So almost identical results. But, when I change for example main.cpp in both projects and do compilation+link, I got this:

```
VS2013:
1>      577 ms  Link                                       1 calls
1>     1261 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls

VS2017
1>     1196 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls
1>     3145 ms  Link                                       1 calls
```

So, the problem seems to be that no mather how many files are linked together, in VS2017 the time is still the same.

Edit2:

Based on @seccur idea I installed also VS2015 toolkit

Again, two same projects, both fully compiled & linked and in both I moddified main.cpp file.

```
VS2015 (2015 v140)
1>       64 ms  WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename              1 calls
1>      594 ms  Link                                       1 calls
1>     1312 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls

VS2017 (2017 v141)
1>       43 ms  WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename              1 calls
1>      754 ms  ClCompile                                  1 calls
1>     2082 ms  Link                                       1 calls
```

Both projects opened in VS2017 IDE, both with same settings, the only difference is toolkit selection. It's more than clear that v141 toolkit is completely bugged.

Comment: Although this is poor by comparison, and I am not saying there isn't a problem here, and I am not saying that you shouldn't try to fix it... does it _really_ "prevent effective development"? Sizeable projects take a _lot_ longer to build than this. I'd give my left leg for 30s build times! Perhaps you are rebuilding too frequently in your workcycle?

Comment: It's not build time for whole project. It's build time + link time when one file is changed in whole project is changed

Comment: Ok - so we're only talking about the link stage - that's a bit more reasonable. Still, I don't quite follow. After you change a file you have to relink everything into a new executable anyway. Why would it matter _how many_ files you changed? Or is that indeed the question here?

Comment: Please, check added example on the bottom of question. When I change one file in VS2013, linking phase takes 500ms, in VS2017 linking phase takes 3000ms no matter if I recompile whole project or if I change only one file

Comment: Again, the work that the linking phase has to do, does not depend on how many files were recompiled before it. Unless MSVS (with which I am admittedly not very familiar) does some extraordinary caching magic. Are you saying that the build process is longer when you have recompiled one file, than when you are rebuilding the whole project?

Comment: Please, take a look at VS2013 vs 2017 comparison. As you can see, VS2013 has such optimizaitons so why VS2017 shouldnt? In case you're not familiar with MSVS you can't help me.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't seem like you're interested in addressing my attempts to obtain clarification. Good luck!

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Win10 receommended if developing in SDK 10 and above. How is the performance while linking with SDK 8.1 and toolset 15 ?

Comment: It's Win10 Pro, 64bit, 16GB ram, Intel i7 770k. Unfortunately I'm not able to try it with SDK 8.1 becasue project depends on several external libraries (libxml, qt, ...) which I'm not able to compile with 8.1

Comment: @seccpur: By toolset 15 you mean v141 in VS2017 15.5.6? Or is there any newer v15 instead of v141?

Comment: typos, i mean toolset v140 SDK 8.1  for win7 & win8 developments. And SDK 10.xxx V141 for win10

Comment: Don't you know if it is necessary to compile/link also all dependent libraries with /DEBUG:FASTLINK?

Comment: @seccpur After a lot of troubles, I managed to compile & run also v140 toolkit with 8.1 SDK. The speed of v140 is good and very similar to 2013 (see new attached benchmarks on the bottom of my post). So, for now, I will use v140 to be able to compile some modern libs (great nlohmann's Json library and pantor's Inja templating library) and to get reasonable performance.

Comment: Are you sure the option /Gm- actually deactive the minimal rebuilt ? no such example on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfz8ad09.aspx  and this option is incompatible with /MP.

Comment: I also see this problem. `link.exe` consumes 0 cpu almost whole time, but after 10 minutes manages to finish the job.